# Convert or remove [short-code] type tags in webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have following `html` in a web-page generated from a vendor's software which contains WordPress style `[short-code]` tags:

```html
<div class="post__entry">
<p>[table]<br>
Room, Tariff, Plan<br>
Triple Room, [rs] 2200, EP<br>
Large Room, [rs] 2500, EP<br>
Single Cottage 1, [rs] 3100, EP<br>
Single Cottage 2, [rs] 3300, EP<br>
[/table]
</p>
</div>
```

I need a javascript to convert the above html to (at least) something like this:

```html
<div class="post__entry">
<p>
Room, Tariff, Plan<br>
Triple Room, ₹ 2200, EP<br>
Large Room, ₹ 2500, EP<br>
Single Cottage 1, ₹ 3100, EP<br>
Single Cottage 2, ₹ 3300, EP<br>
</p>
</div>
```

A super nice presentation will be like this (definitely it is too much to ask for) :
[image]

Comment: get the innerHTML of the p tag and then replace it with what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do simple string replacing using JavaScript's `replace()`, then replace the text back into its container with your modified string.

Targeting everything inside an element with class `post__entry`:

```js
    let postEntry = document.querySelector('.post__entry')
    let postText = postEntry.innerHTML;
    postText = postText.replace(/\[table\]<br>|\[\/table\]/g, '');
    postText = postText.replace(/\[rs\]/g, '₹');
    postEntry.innerHTML = postText;
```

```html
<div class="post__entry">
  <p>[table]<br>
  Room, Tariff, Plan<br>
  Triple Room, [rs] 2200, EP<br>
  Large Room, [rs] 2500, EP<br>
  Single Cottage 1, [rs] 3100, EP<br>
  Single Cottage 2, [rs] 3300, EP<br>
  [/table]
  </p>
</div>
```

The `/g` on the end of the searched text tells JS to replace all matches, not only the first.

Unfortunately, to get your beautiful table presentation will require a lot more work ;)